# Не могу напрямую из объекта вызвать массив по ключу

Tags: javascript

```
_checkLine() {
  let massiv = {
    'x': [this._x],
    'y': [this._y]
  }

  for (let i = 1; i <= this._before; i++) {
    if (massivCell[this._x][this._y - i] && massivCell[this._x][this._y - i] == this._klas) {
      massiv['x'].push(this._x);
      massiv['y'].push(this._y - i);    
    } else { 
      break; 
    }
  }    

  for (let i = 1; i <= this._before; i++) {
    if (massivCell[this._x][this._y + i] && massivCell[this._x][this._y + i] == this._klas) {   
      massiv['x'].push(this._x);
      massiv['y'].push(this._y + i);    
    } else { 
      break; 
    }
  }
  return massiv;    
}

run_check() {
  if (this._checkLine()['x'].length == this._before) {
    return this._checkLine();
  } else if (this._checkColumn()['x'].length == this._before) {
    return this._checkColumn()
  } else if (this._checkDiagonal_1()['x'].length == this._before) {
    return this._checkDiagonal_1()
  } else if (this._checkDiagonal_2()['x'].length == this._before) {
    return this._checkDiagonal_2()
  }
}

borderColor() {
  let masiv = this.run_check();
  let masX = [];
  let masY = [];
  for (let key in masiv) {
    if (key == 'x')
      masX = masiv[key];
    else
      masY = masiv[key];
    }
    console.log(masiv['x'])

    for (let i = 0; i < masX.length; i++) {
      this._DivX[masX[i]].children[masY[i]].classList.add('border');
    }
  }
}
```

Проблема начинается в методе `BorderColor`. Я хотел вывести массив по ключу, то есть `MASIV['X']`, но высвечивается ошибка

> Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Как вы видите дальше, мне пришлось сделать пару манипуляций, чтобы вывести массив. Что интересно, так это то, что FOR OF не работает.

Но я так и не понимаю почему выводится такая ошибка, ведь в методе `run_check` я спокойно могу указать ключ.

Comment: Сравните в коде написание `masiv` и `massiv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что выполнение в `run_check` не заходит ни в один `if`/`else if`, и `this.run_check()` возвращает `undefined`.

```
borderColor() {
    let masiv = this.run_check();
    console.log(masiv); // - ?
    ...
```

Comment: Даа спасибо за ответ)) Действительно, что метод run_check ничего не возвращал, поэтому и ничего не находил.